# Are there bound elementary bosons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, bosons

I know that a pion can take place of an electron in an atom, but pion is not an elementary boson, but a particle made of constituents. However, my question regards elementary particles. Are there bound states for elementary bosons like photons, W, Z etc(maybe something like gluonium - two gluons bound together). And if yes, were they observed or is it only what theory allows?

Comment: I think there were candidates for glueballs, observed in LHC, but I would also like to know the current status on this.

Comment: There have been glueball candidates around since at least the 1980s. Unfortunately, light unflavoured mesons are such a mess of broad, overlapping states that we'll probably never unambiguously identify a glueball. See http://pdg.lbl.gov/2017/reviews/rpp2016-rev-scalar-mesons.pdf and http://pdg.lbl.gov/2017/reviews/rpp2016-rev-non-qqbar-mesons.pdf

Answer (score 2):

In the spirit of "gluonium", there are (hypothetically) [glueballs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glueball) which can have far more than just two gluons. There isn't much else you can do.

You could also have "bound" W bosons, but for example a proton-W system would have the proton orbiting the much more massive W, not vice versa. A $W^+W^-$ system would be short-lived like positronium (assuming the Ws lived long enough for annihilation, but their short lifetime is a problem for any W-binding system).

Failing that you have to hope a weak or gravitational force can give you a bounded elementary boson, though again it may be short-lived.

Comment: Ouch! A positronium lives for a ns, so a millionth of a second. But the Ws in such a hypothetical bound state would decay themselves in $10^{-21}$ sec, no?

Comment: @CosmasZachos It will end quickly due to either annihilation or the particles decaying, but I've not calculated which happens first.

Comment: Yes, i blew a factor of 1000, not that it matters. The width of the W is ~2GeV, so the lifetime is $10^{-24}$ sec.  That's absurdly short, which is why people discuss widths and not lifetimes for such particles.

Comment: The top quark's lifetime is $\sim 5 \times 10^{-25}$, which is smaller than the characteristic timescale of the strong interaction, i.e. too short to form bound states. There's no chance of W bosons forming bound states: the characteristic timescales of the electromagnetic and weak interactions are much longer than that of the strong interaction.